# What branch of science is it that predicts how people in the past thought?

Tags: resource-recommendation

My friend speculated that people in the past believed that the gallbladder has therapeutic properties because of its distinctive color among surrounding meat - greenish among red.
Maybe our ancestors thought it was where our souls resided something similar to Ancient Egyptians' belief that the heart is far more important than the brain.

My question is, how do we begin to research or collect pieces of evidence for this? What keyword should we use? What field of science? Is it archeopsychology?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are looking for. Maybe check out [humorism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humorism)?

Comment: "to predicts how people in the past thought"??? Maybe to "reconstruct"... If so, history and historical anthropology.

Comment: @njuffa, thank you! I had never heard about humorism before!
So, the gallbladder has an actual therapeutic effect. But no one knows why before the technology could support the claim. We were wondering why people believed it in the first place. Conversely, the bull penis for example does not have a similar proven effect, but people consume it, maybe to copy its remarkable performance. (maybe)

#MauroALLEGRANZA, yes probably to reconstruct!